# count sets of dates where set bigger than one

Tags: mysql

Bit of a strange question this one, I'm trying to count sets of dates - but only give one point for each set.

I dont need to count single dates e.g `03/10/2016` and `04/10/2016`

Each group of dates equals one point.

data:

```
01/10/2016
01/10/2016    count as 1
02/10/2016
02/10/2016
02/10/2016    count as 1
03/10/2016    dont count
04/10/2016    dont count
```

The result im looking for would be 2 as there only 2 sets of identical dates
(`01/10/2016` and `02/10/2016`)

so far I have:

```
SELECT 
COUNT(
    DISTINCT (
      action.`actiondate2` 
    )
  ) AS nb
FROM
  ACTION 
GROUP BY actiondate2
HAVING
COUNT(
    DISTINCT (
      action.`actiondate2` 
    )
  ) > 1
```

Comment: HI - dont need to count those dates as are not part of a set

Answer (score 2):

You seem to want to count dates that appear more than once.  I would go with:

```
select count(*)
from (select a.actiondate2, count(*) as cnt
      from action a
      group by a.actiondate2
      having count(*) > 1
     ) a;
```

EDIT:

If you want to just see the dates, use the subquery:

```
      select a.actiondate2
      from action a
      group by a.actiondate2
      having count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: Hi - how do I cap the count at one for each set? for dates 01/10/2016 and 02/10/2016 I would only like the count to be 1 each